Adding a note to Longtable & landscape
I'm new to latex and my tables are still quite messy. I have a few question regarding the following table.

I need to add a note below the table. Unfortunately I only succeed in adding a note at the first page.
Is it possible to manually decide where the table starts the second page?
How can I adjust the width of the columns manually?

This is what I have so far:

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
\item [A1] Standard errors in parentheses\newline 
\item [B] * p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001 
 \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lrrrr@{}}
\caption{here is my caption}
\label{tab:out}\\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}                \\
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}                \\* \midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model4} \\* \midrule
IDV1            & 0.601***     & 0.685***  & 0.025*    & -0.036**  \\
                & (0.116)      & (0.032)   & (0.013)   & (0.014)   \\
Dummy1         & -11.215***   & -6.126*** & -0.221*** & -0.193*** \\
                & (0.116)      & (0.031)   & (0.012)   & (0.012)   \\
Dummy2         & -9.887***    & -6.953*** & -0.221*** & -0.127*** \\
                & (0.122)      & (0.031)   & (0.012)   & (0.012)   \\
Dummy4         & -2.194***    & -0.642*** & -0.050*** & -0.135*** \\
                & (0.118)      & (0.029)   & (0.011)   & (0.013)   \\
Dummy5         & -8.849***    & -5.821*** & -0.126*** & -0.160*** \\
                & (0.120)      & (0.030)   & (0.012)   & (0.013)   \\
Dummy6         & -16.901***   & -8.120*** & -0.348*** & -0.267*** \\
                & (0.118)      & (0.029)   & (0.011)   & (0.012)   \\
Dummy7         & -2.240***    & -0.761*** & -0.006    & -0.193*** \\
                & (0.122)      & (0.030)   & (0.012)   & (0.013)   \\
Dummy8         & -19.537***\} & -7.578*** & -0.396*** & -0.373*** \\
                & (0.111)      & (0.030)   & (0.011)   & (0.013)   \\
Dummy9         & -12.052***   & -6.790*** & -0.209*** & -0.185*** \\
                & (0.121)      & (0.030)   & (0.012)   & (0.013)   \\
Dummy10        & 3.137***     & 0.748***  & 0.125***  & -0.056*** \\
                & (0.127)      & (0.032)   & (0.013)   & (0.014)   \\
Dummy11        & -8.873***    & -5.786*** & -0.107*** & -0.149*** \\
                & (0.122)      & (0.031)   & (0.012)   & (0.014)   \\
Dummy12        & -16.962***   & -7.658*** & -0.330*** & -0.316*** \\
                & (0.120)      & (0.030)   & (0.012)   & (0.013)   \\
Interaction=2  & 0.441**      & -0.125**  & -0.006    & 0.080***  \\
                & (0.158)      & (0.041)   & (0.017)   & (0.016)   \\
Interaction=3  & -10.853***   & -1.084*** & -0.190*** & -0.051**  \\
                & (0.160)      & (0.040)   & (0.016)   & (0.016)   \\
Interaction=4  & -18.710***   & -3.607*** & -0.294*** & -0.066*** \\
                & (0.152)      & (0.041)   & (0.016)   & (0.017)   \\
Interaction=5  & -4.816***    & -0.740*** & -0.088*** & 0.044*    \\
                & (0.160)      & (0.041)   & (0.016)   & (0.018)   \\
Interaction=6  & 5.835***     & 1.046***  & 0.166***  & 0.185***  \\
                & (0.165)      & (0.039)   & (0.016)   & (0.018)   \\
Interaction=7  & 2.209***     & 0.080     & -0.002    & 0.066***  \\
                & (0.176)      & (0.043)   & (0.017)   & (0.018)   \\*\midrule
Observations    & 308953     & 308953  & 308953  & 308953  \\* \bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with \documentclass and end with  \end{document}

you can use e.g. p{3cm}p{5cm} rather than rr when specifying the columns. maybe put the note in \endfoot?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
